# Extracting subset of strings in R?

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have a dataframe like

```
Group            Score
Duck QuackDUC    0.343
Ten TopTEN       0.198
** -Men MaleMEN  0.350
y -Rural AreaRU  0.888
Maple TreeMAP    0.468
Man NavyMN       0.150
```

I want to extract the word in each `Group`, which is the string after the space ' ', and before the 2-3 char string in all caps. That is, I want the result to be

```
Group Score
Quack 0.343
Top   0.198
Male  0.350
Area  0.888
Tree  0.468
Navy  0.150
```

How do I extract these words?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub`.  We match zero or more characters followed by one or more letters followed by one or more space (`\\s+`), keep the uppercase and the letters that follow in capture group (i.e. inside the parentheses `(...)`), and replace it with the backreference to the capture group (`\\1`).

```
df1$Group <- sub(".*[A-Za-z]+\\s+([A-Z][a-z]+).*", "\\1", df1$Group)
df1$Group
#[1] "Quack" "Top"   "Male"  "Area"  "Tree"  "Navy"
```

Comment: For the data provided, `sub(".*([A-Z][a-z]+).*", "\\1", df1$Group)` seems to also work, although your answer is more complete